# MatSort ignores direction when active has changed

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am programmatically sorting a MatSort component, but I don't want to change the direction each time. I am storing the direction, and passing it to the `MatSort.sort()` method, but it seems to get ignored:

```
this.database.sort.sort({
  id: <active>,
  start: <direction>,
  disableClear: this.database.sort.disableClear
});
```

The only work around I have found is to check the sort direction after sorting and resort if it does not match my `direction` value, which is highly inefficient!

Any better solutions or something I am missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Ugly work around**

As mentioned, the only work around I have found is to check the sort direction after sorting and resort if it does not match my `direction` value, which is highly inefficient!

It looks like this:

```js
sort(active: string, direction = this.sort.direction) {
  this.database.sort.sort({
    id: active,
    start: direction,
    disableClear: this.database.sort.disableClear
  });
  if (this.sort.direction !== direction) {
    this.logger.log("Wrong direction, resorting");
    this.sort(active, direction);
  }
}
```

I hope someone can come up with a better solution though!

Answer (score 0):

Issue is still active 2024, Angular V15

**Background:**

`Sort` component exposes a callable event `sortChange()` method, which you can emit to trigger it. Use this instead of the `sort()` method.
the 'sortChange()' event is also called by UI column header click events, on sort enabled columns.

**Workaround**:

```
this.sort.direction = direction;
this.sort.active = activeSortColumnName;
this.sort.sortChange.emit(this.sort);
```

**Component Library Code**

Latest [Github](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/sort/sort.ts) code Angular V17 code for this MatSort.sort method, still shows the same fault. If current active column is not changed (since last sort), then direction is automatically cycled using **getNextSortDirection()** call, ignoring the caller requested, specific sort direction parameter.

```
/** Sets the active sort id and determines the new sort direction. */
sort(sortable: MatSortable): void {
  if (this.active != sortable.id) {
    this.active = sortable.id;
    this.direction = sortable.start ? sortable.start : this.start;
  } else {
    this.direction = this.getNextSortDirection(sortable);
  }

  this.sortChange.emit({active: this.active, direction: this.direction});
}
```